# Access results (in array) of indexedDB request outside

Tags: indexeddb

I am trying to get the value of the iterated objects of one of my objectStore using this code:

```
enter codefunction get_object(object){
    var object = object;
    var obj_list = [];
    var transaction = db.transaction([object],"readonly");
    var obj_store   = transaction.objectStore(object);

    obj_store.openCursor().onsuccess = function (event){
        cursor = event.target.result;
        if(cursor){
            console.log(cursor.value);
            obj_list.push(cursor.value);
            cursor.continue();
        }else{
            console.log("Done processing " + object + "...");
            return obj_list;
        }
    };
}
```

What I want to do is access obj_list outside of the said method?

Comment: What happens when you run that code? You are returning obj_list at the end of the cursor.onsuccess() so i would expect it to be visible

Comment: You may need to return a promise / deferred from this function, and then resolve it in the cursor.onsuccess since the IndexedDB API is asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

Change your main function to something like this:

```
function get_object(object){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var object = object;
        var obj_list = [];
        var transaction = db.transaction([object],"readonly");
        var obj_store   = transaction.objectStore(object);

        obj_store.openCursor().onsuccess = function (event){
            cursor = event.target.result;
            if(cursor){
                console.log(cursor.value);
                obj_list.push(cursor.value);
                cursor.continue();
            }else{
                console.log("Done processing " + object + "...");
                resolve(obj_list);
            }
        };
    });
}
```

Then to access it:

```
get_object('some_object').then(function (returned_data) {
    console.log(returned_data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Jonny shows the correct path. If you are not a JS geek and don't want to use promises and believe in callback methods and then a simple looking code will be as below:

```
function get_object(object, callBack){
    var object = object;
    var obj_list = [];
    var transaction = db.transaction([object],"readonly");
    var obj_store   = transaction.objectStore(object);

    obj_store.openCursor().onsuccess = function (event){
        cursor = event.target.result;
        if(cursor){
            console.log(cursor.value);
            obj_list.push(cursor.value);
            cursor.continue();
        }else{
            console.log("Done processing " + object + "...");
            if (callBack && typeof(callBack) == 'function') {
                callBack(obj_list);
            }
            return;
        }
    };
}
```

And then use it as:

```
get_object("data_store", callBack);
function get_object_result_processor(resultSet){
    //Do something
}
```